# How can I determine the position of my tango device with tango-support?

Tags: google-project-tango

I want to use TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_GLOBAL_WGS84 to determinate the position of my device compare to the world.

My code looks this :

```
glm::mat4 matrixDeviceToWGS;
glm::vec4 originDeviceInDevice = glm::vec4(glm::vec3(0.0), 1.0);
glm::vec4 originDeviceInWGS;
glm::vec4 northPoleInWGS = glm::vec4(glm::vec2(0.0), SEMI_MINOR_AXIS_WGS, 1.0);
glm::vec4 northPoleInDevice;

TangoMatrixTransformData matrix_transform;
TangoSupport_getMatrixTransformAtTime(
        i_timestamp, TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE, TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_GLOBAL_WGS84,
        TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_TANGO, TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_TANGO,
        ROTATION_0,
        &matrix_transform);
if (matrix_transform.status_code == TANGO_POSE_VALID) {

    matrixDeviceToWGS = glm::make_mat4(matrix_transform.matrix);
    originDeviceInWGS = matrixDeviceToWGS * originDeviceInDevice;
    northPoleInDevice = -originDeviceInWGS + northPoleInWGS;
}
```

But I can't pass the condition TANGO_POSE_VALID, I have only TANGO_POSE_INVALID.
Does anyone know if my code is correct, or at least if the enum TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_GLOBAL_WGS84 is implemented ?